# Linq Collection instersection List/Array

Tags: entity-framework, linq, list, linq-to-entities

Consider the following list:

```
List<long> listOfIDs = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

> [(Product) 1 Pineapple - (Supplier) Fruit Inc / Marketplace Inc]>
>
> [2 Strawberry - Fruit Inc]>
>
> [3 Coke - Super Drinks Inc / Marketplace Inc]>
>
> [4 Orange Juice - Super Drinks Inc]

```
db.Table.Where(a => a.SubTable.All(b => listOfIds.Contains(b.SubTableId)))
```

While I've selected Products 1 and 2, I should get only Fruit Inc as a Supplier. When I include Coke into my list, I **don't want to see any supplier anymore** because there is no Supplier that represents these 3 products at the same time.

Expected Outputs Scenarios:

Selected Products: 1, 2
Expected Result: Fruit Inc

1, 3
Marketplace Inc

1, 2, 3
**Empty.**

1, 3, 4
**Empty.**

3, 4
Super Drinks Inc

Comment: And what is the result of your query?

Comment: Database tables don't have sub tables. Do you mean table fields?

Comment: @Slai just consider them as collections. That is just a sample to clarify what I need to reach.

Comment: @octavioccl imagine this scenario **[SupplierA has Products 1 & 2]**, **[SupplierB has Product 3]** and **[SupplierC has Product 2 & 3]** the expected result are **Supplier A and C** because they are only the ones that have Product 2 mutual.

Comment: Yes, but B and C have 3 mutual too, sorry, but I haven't understood yet what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: @octavioccl you are right, it's not being so easy to explain. My apologize. Try to imagine the following situation: 
[(Product) **1 Pineapple** - (Supplier) **Fruit Inc**] / 
[**2 Strawberry** - (Supplier) **Fruit Inc**] / 
[**3 Coke** - (Supplier) **Super Drinks Inc**]. While I've selected Products 1 and 2, I should get Fruit Inc as a Supplier. When I include Coke into my list, I don't want to see any supplier anymore because there is no Supplier that represents these 3 products at the same time.

Comment: But according to your query a product could have several providers, if you can, please update your question with the current result of your query, something like  this is what I'm getting know and this is the expected result and the design of your entities

Comment: @octavioccl that's true, my product could have more than one provider, that's not wrong. Please, take a look again my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
// change All to Select if you want list of each bool
     db.Table.All(a => listOfIds.Contains(a.SubTableId));
```

This should do the trick if you want to check if listOfIds exists in the db since you mentioned ContainsAll.

If you want to get the entities from db with listOfIds then this should do it.

```
 db.Table.Where(a => listOfIds.Contains(a.SubTableId)).ToList;
```

Comment: doing this I get an error saying "bool does not contain a definition for Select". I might not expressed myself so clear... imagine thes scenario **[SupplierA has Products 1 & 2]**, **[SupplierB has Product 3]** and **[SupplierC has Product 2 & 3]** the expected result are **Supplier A and C** because they are only the ones that have Product 2 mutual.

Comment: Could you share your model?

Comment: `public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}`